# How pass a value from MainActivity to ServiceConnection?

Tags: java, android, service, inner-classes

I have a `MainActivity` with a `private String attribute`. In my code I have the following:

```
private ServiceConnection mTransactionServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
        mTransactionService = IPoyntTransactionService.Stub.asInterface(iBinder);
        Log.d(TAG, "Transaction service connected");
        try {
            mTransactionService.getTransaction("fcf98959-c188-42d1-b085-786d21e552ac", UUID.randomUUID().toString(), mTransactionServiceListener);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        mTransactionService = null;
        Log.d(TAG, "Transaction service disconnected");
    }
};
```

The value: `fcf98959-c188-42d1-b085-786d21e552ac` is hardcoded. I need to put a string that I have in the attributes in the `MainActivity`. How can I do this?

I tried to make the string as public, as static but does not work.

Comment: don't make that string static in your activity and then access it anywhere. You'll only cause memory leaks

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in your service that will work like a setter for example:

```
public void setValue(String value){
   this.value = value;
}
```

Inside your onServiceConnected() function

and call it from your onServiceConnected() after yo init the Service you can use functions that inside it.

```
private ServiceConnection mTransactionServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
        mTransactionService = IPoyntTransactionService.Stub.asInterface(iBinder);
        Log.d(TAG, "Transaction service connected");
         **mTransactionService.setValue(the value your want to set);**
        try {
            mTransactionService.getTransaction("fcf98959-c188-42d1-b085-786d21e552ac", UUID.randomUUID().toString(), mTransactionServiceListener);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        mTransactionService = null;
        Log.d(TAG, "Transaction service disconnected");
    }
};
```

this will update the value at the service.
You can also use the service functions from out side the onServiceConnected, just make sure it's not null.

Comment: I dont understand. I create a setter for this value in the service, but how can i assign the value that is in mainActivity? i can't read any variable from the outside of the service.

Comment: I edited my answer, take a look and tell me if it's more understandable now

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear. However, as far as I could understand, you might consider having a `public static` variable in your `MainActivity` which can be used anywhere in your code.

Hence, define the `attribute` variable like the following in your `MainActivity`.

```
public static String attribute = "fcf98959-c188-42d1-b085-786d21e552ac";
```

Now use this in the `ServiceConnection` as follows.

```
mTransactionService.getTransaction(MainActivity.attribute, UUID.randomUUID().toString(), mTransactionServiceListener);
```

Comment: The long string is the result of another service. That long string is different everytime the user press a button. I need to pass it as a variable into the serviceConnection. In the example that string is hardcoded but in the real app it needs to be a variable. The variable is set outside, in another function in the mainActivity. I create an attribute for this value, but i cannot use the variable inside the serviceConnection.

Comment: I understand it now. I removed the second part of my answer as well. You just have to use the attribute like the way I showed above in the `ServiceConnection`. I am still not sure why you are not being able to do this. What is the error that you are getting while putting this as a `public static` variable as I mentioned in my answer?